# dates of past 12 months in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

Need a query that lists all the dates of the past 12 months

say my current date is 10-21-2013. need to use sysdate to get the data

The result should look like

```
10/21/2013
...
10/01/2013
09/30/2013
...
09/01/2013
...
01/31/2013
...
01/01/2013
...
11/30/2012
...
11/01/2012
```

Please help me with this..
Thanks in advance.

AVG

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to populate calendar table in Oracle?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8374959/how-to-populate-calendar-table-in-oracle)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Allowing for leap years and all, by using add_months to work out the date 12 months ago and thus how many rows to generate ...

```
select trunc(sysdate) - rownum + 1 the_date
from   dual
connect by level <= (trunc(sysdate) - add_months(trunc(sysdate),-12))
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
select to_date('21-oct-2012','dd-mon-yyyy') + rownum -1
from all_objects
where rownum <= 
    to_date('21-oct-2013','dd-mon-yyyy') - to_date('21-oct-2012','dd-mon-yyyy')+1
```

of course, you could use parameters for the start and end date to make it more usable.

-or- using sysdate, like this:

```
select sysdate + interval '-1' year + rownum -1
from all_objects
where rownum <= 
    sysdate - (sysdate + interval '-1' year)
```

Comment: `all_objects` fails in the case of schemas that have access to very few objects

Comment: It can also be fairly slow where there are complex sets of roles in place.

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this

SELECT SYSDATE,
       SYSDATE-1,
       <continue>   
       SYSDATE-30,         
       <continue>
        .........
       <continue>    
       SYSDATE-364,
       SYSDATE-365

FROM DUAL;
```

Comment: is there an easy solution. I read a few posts where in they used 'Connect by' clause to get this done.