# Query Date Ranges with select statement

Tags: sql, oracle

i want to know that is this possible with select statement query to generate date ranges (i.e start_date column and end_date column) for interval of 10 days up-to 62 days back to sysdate. like below

**result required like**

[image]
please help anyone

thanking you

Comment: Yes its possible.  Couple of approaches found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29634180/oracle-sql-fill-in-missing-dates)

Answer (score 1):

Addressing the original version of the question:

**Query 1 - Hierarchical Query**:

```
SELECT TRUNC( SYSDATE ) - LEVEL * 10 AS start_date,
       TRUNC( SYSDATE ) - ( LEVEL - 1 ) * 10 AS end_date
FROM   DUAL
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 5
```

**Query 2 - Recursive Sub-query**:

```
WITH rsqfc ( end_date, lvl ) AS (
  SELECT CAST( TRUNC( SYSDATE ) AS DATE ), 1 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL
  SELECT end_date - 10, lvl + 1
  FROM   rsqfc
  WHERE  lvl < 5
)
SELECT end_date - 10 AS start_date,
       end_date
FROM   rsqfc;
```

**Output**:

*(Both output the same)*

```
START_DATE          END_DATE          
------------------- -------------------
2016-05-28 00:00:00 2016-06-07 00:00:00 
2016-05-18 00:00:00 2016-05-28 00:00:00 
2016-05-08 00:00:00 2016-05-18 00:00:00 
2016-04-28 00:00:00 2016-05-08 00:00:00 
2016-04-18 00:00:00 2016-04-28 00:00:00
```

Update: Addressing the edit - just change the interval and use `GREATEST` OR `LEAST`:

**Query 1 - Hierarchical Query**:

```
SELECT TRUNC( SYSDATE ) - LEAST( 62, LEVEL * 11 ) AS start_date,
       TRUNC( SYSDATE ) - ( LEVEL - 1 ) * 10 AS end_date
FROM   DUAL
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 6
```

**Query 1 - Recursive Sub-Query**:

```
WITH rsqfc ( end_date, lvl ) AS (
  SELECT CAST( TRUNC( SYSDATE ) AS DATE ), 1 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL
  SELECT end_date - 11, lvl + 1
  FROM   rsqfc
  WHERE  lvl < 6
)
SELECT GREATEST( TRUNC( SYSDATE ) - 62, end_date - 10 ) AS start_date,
       end_date
FROM   rsqfc;
```

**Output**:

```
START_DATE          END_DATE          
------------------- -------------------
2016-05-28 00:00:00 2016-06-08 00:00:00 
2016-05-17 00:00:00 2016-05-29 00:00:00 
2016-05-06 00:00:00 2016-05-19 00:00:00 
2016-04-25 00:00:00 2016-05-09 00:00:00 
2016-04-14 00:00:00 2016-04-29 00:00:00 
2016-04-07 00:00:00 2016-04-19 00:00:00
```

Comment: Downvoter care to comment - please note that the question has changed since the original and this addresses the original version.

Answer (score 0):

I see this is a little more tricky after seeing your edits.  You would still use a recursive query to generate the date ranges but then since the last date range can actually be less than 10 days, you have to add a case statement to limit it to 62 days.

First part of the recursive query sets the END_DT = SYSDATE and the START_DT to SYSDATE - 10 days.  The second part keeps subtracting from the dates until you hit 70 days.  Then the select statement changes the last START_DT to 62 days.

```
with cte(START_DT, END_DT) 
as(
  select 
  trunc(SYSDATE) - 10  as START_DT, 
  trunc(SYSDATE)       as END_DT 
from dual
union all
  Select 
  START_DT - 11 as START_DT, 
  START_DT - 1  as END_DT
from cte
where START_DT - 11 >= trunc(SYSDATE) - 70
)    

select 
  case when trunc(START_DT) < trunc(SYSDATE) - 62 
       then trunc(SYSDATE) - 62 
       else START_DT
  end START_DT,
  END_DT
from cte
order by start_dt desc
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
START_DT             END_DT             
-------------------- --------------------
29-MAY-2016 00:00:00 08-JUN-2016 00:00:00 
18-MAY-2016 00:00:00 28-MAY-2016 00:00:00 
07-MAY-2016 00:00:00 17-MAY-2016 00:00:00 
26-APR-2016 00:00:00 06-MAY-2016 00:00:00 
15-APR-2016 00:00:00 25-APR-2016 00:00:00 
07-APR-2016 00:00:00 14-APR-2016 00:00:00
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate more your answer adding a little more description about the solution you provide?