# SQL query that finds dates between a range and takes values from another query & iterates range over them?

Tags: sql, oracle

Sorry if the wording for this question is strange. Wasn't sure how to word it, but here's the context:

I'm working on an application that shows some data about the how often individual applications are being used when users make a request from my web server. The way we take data is by every time the start page loads, it increments a data table called WEB_TRACKING at the date of when it loaded. So there are a lot of holes in data, for example, an application might've been used heavily on September 1st but not at all September 2nd. What I want to do, is add those holes with a value on hits of 0.  This is what I came up with.

```
Select HIT_DATA.DATE_ACCESSED, HIT_DATA.APP_ID, HIT_DATA.NAME, WORKDAYS.BENCH_DAYS, NVL(HIT_DATA.HITS, 0) from (
    select DISTINCT( TO_CHAR(WEB.ACCESS_TIME, 'MM/DD/YYYY')) as BENCH_DAYS 
    FROM WEB_TRACKING WEB        
) workDays
LEFT join (
    SELECT TO_CHAR(WEB.ACCESS_TIME, 'MM/DD/YYYY') as DATE_ACCESSED, APP.APP_ID, APP.NAME,
    COUNT(WEB.IP_ADDRESS) AS HITS
    FROM WEB_TRACKING WEB
    INNER JOIN WEB_APP APP ON WEB.APP_ID = APP.APP_ID
    WHERE APP.IS_ENABLED = 1  AND (APP.APP_ID = 1 OR APP.APP_ID = 2)
        AND (WEB.ACCESS_TIME > TO_DATE('08/04/2018', 'MM/DD/YYYY') 
        AND WEB.ACCESS_TIME < TO_DATE('09/04/2018', 'MM/DD/YYYY')) 
    GROUP BY TO_CHAR(WEB.ACCESS_TIME, 'MM/DD/YYYY'), APP.APP_ID, APP.NAME
    ORDER BY TO_CHAR(WEB.ACCESS_TIME, 'MM/DD/YYYY'), app_id DESC
) HIT_DATA ON HIT_DATA.DATE_ACCESSED = WORKDAYS.BENCH_DAYS
ORDER BY WORKDAYS.BENCH_DAYS
```

It returns all the dates that between the date range and even converts null hits to 0. However, it returns null for app id and app name. Which makes sense, and I understand how to give a default value for 1 application. I was hoping someone could help me figure out how to do it for multiple applications.

Basically, I am getting this (in the case of using just one application):

```
   | APP_ID | NAME       | BENCH_DAYS | HITS |
   | ------ | ---------- | ---------- | ---- |
   |  NULL  | NULL       | 08/04/2018 | 0    |
   |  1     | test_app   | 08/05/2018 | 1    |
   |  NULL  | NULL       | 08/06/2018 | 0    |
```

But I want this(with multiple applications):

```
   | APP_ID | NAME       | BENCH_DAYS | HITS |
   | ------ | ---------- | ---------- | ---- |
   |  1     | test_app   | 08/04/2018 | 0    |<- these 0's are converted from null
   |  1     | test_app   | 08/05/2018 | 1    |
   |  1     | test_app   | 08/06/2018 | 0    | <- these 0's are converted from null
   |  2     | prod_app   | 08/04/2018 | 2    |
   |  2     | prod_app   | 08/05/2018 | 0    | <- these 0's are converted from null
```

So again to reiterate the question in this long post. How should I go about populating this query so that it fills up the holes in the dates but also reuses the application names and ids and populates that information as well?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Your query seems to be a typical "how to fill in gaps in dates in oracle" and a web search for this should return plenty of hits. One example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29634180/oracle-sql-fill-in-missing-dates

Comment: @Caius Jard Hmm that's what I thought and I found a solution that I thought was fitting but ended up being not quite what I was looking for. Oh well, just gonna have to do more research I guess. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a list of dates, that probably comes from a number generator rather than a table (if that table has holes, your report will too)

Example, every date for the past 30 days:

```
select trunc(sysdate-30) + level as bench_days from dual connect by level < 30
```

Use TRUNC instead of turning a date into a string in order to cut the time off

Now you have a list of dates, you want to add in repeating app id and name:

```
select * from

    (select trunc(sysdate-30) + level as bench_days from dual connect by level < 30) dat
    CROSS JOIN
    (select app_id, name from WEB_APP WHERE APP.IS_ENABLED = 1 AND APP_ID in (1, 2) app
```

Now you have all your dates, crossed with all your apps. 2 apps and 30 days will make a 60 row resultset via a cross join. Left join your stat data onto it, and group/count/sum/aggregate ...

```
select app.app_id, app.name, dat.artificialday, COALESCE(stat.ct, 0) as hits from

    (select trunc(sysdate-30) + level as artificialday from dual connect by level < 30) dat
    CROSS JOIN
    (select app_id, name from WEB_APP WHERE APP.IS_ENABLED = 1 AND APP_ID in (1, 2) app
    LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT app_id, trunc(access_time) accdate, count(ip_address) ct from web_tracking group by app_id, trunc(access_time)) stat
    ON
      stat.app_id = app.app_id AND
      stat.accdate = dat.artificialday
```

You don't have to write the query this way/do your grouping as a subquery, I'm just representing it this way to lead you to thinking about your data in blocks, that you build in isolation and join together later, to build more comprehensive blocks

Comment: Thank you for taking the time. This information really helped :D