# Oracle SQL - Add missing dates into query for each unique value in another column

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to make a query in Oracle SQL from the below table and my goal is to add in the missing days for each store.

```
    +------------+-------+-------+
    |    Date    | Store | Sales |
    +------------+-------+-------+
    | 01/01/2018 | A     |    20 |
    | 01/03/2018 | A     |    30 |
    | 01/02/2018 | B     |    10 |
    | 01/03/2018 | B     |    40 |
    | 01/04/2018 | B     |    50 |
    | 01/01/2018 | C     |    20 |
    +------------+-------+-------+
```

Desired Output:

```
    +------------+-------+-------+
    |    Date    | Store | Sales |
    +------------+-------+-------+
    | 01/01/2018 | A     |    20 |
    | 01/02/2018 | A     |     0 |
    | 01/03/2018 | A     |    30 |
    | 01/04/2018 | A     |     0 |
    | 01/01/2018 | B     |     0 |
    | 01/02/2018 | B     |    10 |
    | 01/03/2018 | B     |    40 |
    | 01/04/2018 | B     |    50 |
    | 01/01/2018 | C     |    20 |
    | 01/02/2018 | C     |     0 |
    | 01/03/2018 | C     |     0 |
    | 01/04/2018 | C     |     0 |
    +------------+-------+-------+
```

I have the 4 days I need from [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29634180/oracle-sql-fill-in-missing-dates), however I cannot make my output look like the desired output. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Use a `cross join` to generate the rows and then `left join` to bring in the data:

```
select s.store, d.date, coalesce(t.sales, 0) as sales
from (select distinct store from t) s cross join
     (select distinct date from t) d left join
     t
     on t.store = s.store and t.date = t.date;
```

Comment: Wow it only took you 1 min to reply! Thank you!!

Comment: It worked!! I spent HOURS on this. Thank you so much Gordon!

Answer (score 0):

One option is to join to a *calendar* table:

```
WITH calendar AS (
    SELECT date '2018-01-01' AS "Date" FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT date '2018-02-01' FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT date '2018-03-01' FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT date '2018-04-01' FROM dual
)     

SELECT
    c."Date",
    s.Store,
    COALESCE(t.Sales, 0) AS Sales
FROM calendar c
CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT Store FROM yourTable) s
LEFT JOIN yourTable t
    ON t."Date" = c."Date" AND t.Store = s.Store;
```

Using a formal calendar table may be necessary here, because perhaps your current table data set does not contain all dates which you wish to appear in the final report.