# SQL Query Display Every Day of the Month/Year Even If No Data Available

Tags: php, sql, oracle

I want to

> display all the days of the month/year (365 days)

in a SQL statement or PHP and then link that day up with data in my table. If there is no data for that day then it must display a null or may be empty.

My table just like this:

```
NO       PRICE       DATE        DESC
======================================
1.       230000     6/25/2019         
2.       200000     8/14/2019
3.       100000     9/29/2019
4.       300000     7/10/2019
```

and my expected table just like this:

```
NO       PRICE       DATE        DESC
======================================
1.       null      01/01/2019         
2.       null      01/02/2019
3.       null      01/03/2019
4.       null      01/04/2019
...                .........      
...                .........      
181.     230000     6/25/2019
```

I've tried some query :

```
public function getData()
{
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM TB_PRICE WHERE '".$date'" 
                               BETWEEN '01/01/2019' AND '01/01/2020')->result(); 
}
```

But it didn't work as I expected.

Any well thought to advise will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29634180/oracle-sql-fill-in-missing-dates