# How to select all month of user selected year in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to make a query with two tables. I want to show all months of the user selected year even if there are no records in the tables. However I can't show the all the months and no null values at all. Please help?

Here is my query:

```
SELECT     spendList.NUMBER, 
           spendList.User, 
           TO_CHAR(spendList.DATE, 'Month') as Month, 
           spendList.AMOUNT, allowence.FUND
FROM       T_EXPENDITURE spendList
LEFT JOIN  T_ALLOWENCE allowence
ON         spendList.DEP_NO = allowence.DEP_NO
WHERE      TO_CHAR(spendList.DATE, 'YYYY') = :userYear
ORDER BY   spendList.DEPARTMENT
```

Results must be like:

```
NUMBER   USER    MONTH      SPEND_AMOUNT   ALLOWENCE
12345    Clerk   January      123             2500
7869     Manager February     150             3000
12345    Clerk   March                        2500
7869     Manager April                        3000
12345    Clerk   May                          2500
7869     Manager June                         3000
12345    Clerk   July                         2500
7869     Manager August                       3000
12345    Clerk   September                    2500
7869     Manager September                    3000
12345    Clerk   October                      2500
7869     Manager Nevember                     3000
12345    Clerk   December                     2500
```

I would use this results in a report and in the report there sould be all the months of the year.

Report would be like:

```
NUMBER   USER    January February ... December    ALLOWENCE
12345    Clerk     123      null         null        2500
```

Comment: Approach that uses `DBA_TABLES` to generate enough rows: http://www.orafaq.com/node/2029

Comment: And the search term you're looking for is "calendar table" or "calendar view".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to populate calendar table in Oracle?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8374959/how-to-populate-calendar-table-in-oracle)

Comment: Your posted expected results don't demonstrate the problem you want to solve, i.e. empty months.

Comment: Why are your expected results alternating months between users and not having 12 months for each user? What happens if the Clerk spent something in February or if they had two entries for a month? If you had 3 users would you expect there to be a row for each user every third month?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `PARTITION` join:

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE T_EXPENDITURE ( "NUMBER", "USER", "DATE", amount, dep_no ) AS
  SELECT 1, 'Clerk',   DATE '2017-01-10',  50, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, 'Clerk',   DATE '2017-01-15',  73, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, 'Clerk',   DATE '2017-02-14',  13, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 'Manager', DATE '2017-02-01', 150, 2 FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE T_ALLOWENCE ( dep_no, fund ) AS
  SELECT 1, 2500 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, 3000 FROM DUAL;
```

**Query**:

```
SELECT e."NUMBER",
       e."USER",
       c.month,
       SUM( e.amount ) AS amount,
       e.fund
FROM
  (
    SELECT e.*, a.fund
    FROM   t_allowance a
           INNER JOIN t_expenditure e
           ON ( e.dep_no = a.dep_no )
  ) e
  PARTITION BY ( e."NUMBER", e."USER", e.FUND )
  RIGHT OUTER JOIN
  (
    SELECT ADD_MONTHS( TO_DATE( :useryear || '0101', 'YYYYMMDD' ), LEVEL - 1 ) AS month
    FROM DUAL
    CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 12
  ) c
  ON( c.month <= e."DATE" AND e."DATE" < ADD_MONTHS( c.month, 1 ) )
GROUP BY e."NUMBER", e."USER", e.FUND, c.MONTH
ORDER BY e."NUMBER", c.MONTH;
```

**Output**:

```
NUMBER USER    MONTH      AMOUNT FUND
------ ------- ---------- ------ ----
     1 Clerk   2017-01-01    123 2500
     1 Clerk   2017-02-01     13 2500
     1 Clerk   2017-03-01        2500
     1 Clerk   2017-04-01        2500
     1 Clerk   2017-05-01        2500
     1 Clerk   2017-06-01        2500
     1 Clerk   2017-07-01        2500
     1 Clerk   2017-08-01        2500
     1 Clerk   2017-09-01        2500
     1 Clerk   2017-10-01        2500
     1 Clerk   2017-11-01        2500
     1 Clerk   2017-12-01        2500
     2 Manager 2017-01-01        3000
     2 Manager 2017-02-01    150 3000
     2 Manager 2017-03-01        3000
     2 Manager 2017-04-01        3000
     2 Manager 2017-05-01        3000
     2 Manager 2017-06-01        3000
     2 Manager 2017-07-01        3000
     2 Manager 2017-08-01        3000
     2 Manager 2017-09-01        3000
     2 Manager 2017-10-01        3000
     2 Manager 2017-11-01        3000
     2 Manager 2017-12-01        3000
```

**Query 2**:

```
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT "NUMBER",
         "USER",
         EXTRACT( MONTH FROM "DATE" ) AS month,
         amount,
         e.dep_no,
         fund
  FROM   T_EXPENDITURE e
         INNER JOIN T_ALLOWENCE a
         ON ( e.dep_no = a.dep_no )
  WHERE  EXTRACT( YEAR FROM e."DATE" ) = :useryear
)
PIVOT (
  SUM( amount )
  FOR month IN (
     1 AS Jan,  2 AS Feb,  3 AS Mar,  4 AS Apr,  5 AS May,  6 AS Jun,
     7 AS Jul,  8 AS Aug,  9 AS Sep, 10 AS Oct, 11 AS Nov, 12 AS Dec
  )
);
```

**Output**:

```
NUMBER USER    DEP_NO FUND JAN FEB MAR APR MAY JUN JUL AUG SEP OCT NOV DEC
------ ------- ------ ---- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- ---
     1 Clerk        1 2500 123  13
     2 Manager      2 3000     150
```

Comment: @T.Rifle The query does not give an error for me; please check that you have copied it correctly. I have also added an update that matches your updated report format. In future please (a) ask the full question first rather than giving an [XY-problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) where you assume a partial solution and (b) do not change your question's output so dramatically as this will invalidate some answers.

Answer (score 1):

This solution uses the WITH clause syntax to generate a subquery of all the months of the year (technically the first day of each month). It assumes `:userYear` is passed as a four-digit number which is cast to a date, then truncated with a `yyyy` mask to get the first day of the year. `add_months()` is used to get the remaining months.

This sub-query is outer joined to your T_EXPENDITURE table by deriving the first day of month for each record.

```
with calendar as (
    select add_months(trunc(to_date(:userYear,'yyyy'),'yyyy'), level-1) as mon
    from dual
    connect by level <=12)
SELECT to_char(calendar.mon,'MONTH')  as Month,
       spendList.NUMBER, 
        spendList.User, 
       spendList.AMOUNT, 
       allowence.FUND
FROM calendar
left join  T_EXPENDITURE spendList
    on  trunc(spendList.DATE, 'MON') = calendar.mon
LEFT JOIN T_ALLOWENCE allowence
ON spendList.DEP_NO=allowence.DEP_NO
ORDER BY spendList.DEPARTMENT
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it gives the same result. I want to show all months even they have null values.

Comment: I have just amended the query: please try it again. If it still doesn't work you'll need to post some sample data.