# OR clause with subquery taking too much time

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, query-optimization

Date Range query taking too much time. 
Just i removed the one condition then it working fine taking 2 second. If adding 
then 30 seconds.

```
SELECT UserName,COUNT ('t') TOTAL
FROM TRANSACTIONS E1
WHERE E1.START_DATE BETWEEN TO_DATE ('20130101', 'YYYYMMDD') AND TO_DATE ('20140101', 'YYYYMMDD')
AND 
( 
    TO_CHAR (E1.START_DATE, 'D') in ( 7) 
    OR Exists(SELECT 1 FROM HOLIDAYS TT
    WHERE E1.START_DATE BETWEEN TT.DATE_FROM AND TT.DATE_TO )
)
AND EXISTS (SELECT 't' FROM TRANSACTIONS_ORG E2 WHERE E1.TRANTYPE = E2.tran_type)
GROUP BY UserName;
```

**HOLIDAYS table**

```
Id  FromDate    ToDate  Description
1   1-Feb-11    3-Feb-11    Maintance
3   2-Sep-09    5-Sep-09    Eid Holiday Fine Block
4   3-Dec-09    4-Dec-09    Due to System Problem
5   4-Dec-07    04-Dec-07   National Day
```

**EIDTED**
I figured out that the issue is not in the date range. but the **OR** clause in the

```
TO_CHAR (E1.START_DATE, 'D') in ( 5,6) 
OR 
Exists(SELECT 1 FROM HOLIDAYS TT
WHERE E1.START_DATE BETWEEN TT.DATE_FROM AND TT.DATE_TO )
```

if removed **OR** and put **AND** then fine and if shuffle conditions with OR still same issue.

Comment: `HOLIDAYS` table `START_DATE` is it indexed?

Comment: @RehanAzher yes indexed on `id`

Comment: Try to index on START_DATE as well.

Comment: And shouldn't this `Exists(SELECT count(TT.DATE_FROM) FROM HOLIDAYS TT
    WHERE START_DATE BETWEEN TT.DATE_FROM AND TT.DATE_TO )` be `Exists(SELECT count(START_DATE) FROM HOLIDAYS TT
    WHERE START_DATE BETWEEN TT.DATE_FROM AND TT.DATE_TO )`

Comment: why do you need "count(TT.DATE_FROM)" maybe just use 1 (select 1 from...)

Comment: What is the output time of this query: `SELECT count(START_DATE) FROM HOLIDAYS TT WHERE START_DATE BETWEEN TT.DATE_FROM AND TT.DATE_TO `

Comment: yes tried with scalor value but still same

Comment: @RehanAzher its 30 sec with subquery

Comment: I mean can u just execute the sub-query separately to check how much it is taking.  with and without index on `START_DATE`

Comment: Its just 100 row. Mili second

Comment: can you add exec plan? it would be easy understand where you have the performance issue

Comment: And please remove the count so that the plan is for "select 1 from ...".

Comment: @user2612030 Yes removed. but still same issue

Comment: Note, result of `TO_CHAR (..., 'D')` depends on current user session `NLS_TERRITORY` setting which may change at any time. Better use `TO_CHAR(..., 'Dy', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=American') IN ('Sat','Sun')`

Comment: Does the sample you have posted represent the actual contents of the `HOLIDAYS` table? How many rows in the table?

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit but problem is not in the weekend days. only in the subquery. how can i rewrite this query?

Comment: @APC yes actual values.

Comment: Please post the results of an Explain plan. Without that its just shooting in the dark.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is likely with the `OR <subquery>` construct.
If there can only be **one** holiday for a particular date, then you could use the following:

```
select username
      ,count(*)
  from transactions  e1
  left join holidays tt on(e1.start_date between tt.date_from and tt.date_to)
 where e1.start_date between date '2017-02-01' and date '2018-02-01'
   and (   to_char(e1.start_date, 'D') in(5, 6) 
        or tt.date_from is not null)
       )
   and exists(
      select * 
        from transactions_org e2 
       where e1.trantype = e2.tran_type
   )
 group 
    by username;
```

This entire category of problems can be solved by implementing a [Calendar table](https://www.google.se/search?hl=sv&safe=off&q=sql%20Calendar%20table&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=). If you had such a table with one record per date, you could easily add columns indicating day of week and holiday flags and such. If your calendar table looked something like this:

```
DAY        DAYNAME   IS_WEEKEND IS_WEEKDAY HOLINAME
---------- --------- ---------- ---------- ------------
2017-02-01 WEDNESDAY          0          1
2017-02-02 THURSDAY           0          1
2017-02-03 FRIDAY             0          1 Some holiday
2017-02-04 SATURDAY           1          0
2017-02-05 SUNDAY             1          0
2017-02-06 MONDAY             0          1
2017-02-07 TUESDAY            0          1
2017-02-08 WEDNESDAY          0          1
```

Your query could be rewritten as:

```
  from transactions  e1
  join calendar      c on(c.day = trunc(e1.start_date, 'DD')) -- Remove hours, minutes
 where e1.start_date between date '2017-02-01' and date '2018-02-01'
   and (   c.weekday in('THURSDAY', 'FRIDAY') -- Either specific weekdays
        or c.holiname is not null             -- or there is a holiday 
       )
   and exists(
      select * 
        from transactions_org e2 
       where e1.trantype = e2.tran_type
   )
```

Comment: +1 for providing a solution with a calendar table! 99% of all calendar related performance problems can be solved with a good calendar table: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8374959/how-to-populate-calendar-table-in-oracle

Comment: @Oliver - to be fair, the OP's question includes their HOLIDAYS table